# Why do I get Unexpected token error for {}.toString() in browser but not in Node?

Tags: javascript

I am asking to understand what is exact correct syntax for `.` operator.

In browser:

```
{}.toString()
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

In node:

```
> {}.toString()
'[object Object]'
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Node 0.10.11 repl. Outputs `[object Object]`

Comment: I'm using node .8 and getting same output

Comment: Works fine in browser too, Chrome 27 reports `[object Object]` http://jsbin.com/ebeput/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs: If you use `console.log`. Typing it into the browser’s console will throw the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess the console interprets `{` as a block first for some reason. Don't know the answer.

Comment: @elclanrs: [Block comes before ExpressionStatement.](http://es5.github.io/#x12) See also [the note on ExpressionStatement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.4).

Comment: @minitech But why is it fine inside js code run in an HTML page?

Comment: @bfavaretto: It’s not. It’s fine inside a place where an expression is expected, e.g. as an argument to `console.log`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node’s REPL does some things with your lines (trying it without parentheses if there’s a syntax error, <del>if I recall correctly</del> [as seen in the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L253)) that make life easier. `{` at the beginning of a statement will otherwise be treated as a code block, and not an object.

Wrap it in parentheses to force it to be treated as an object literal:

```
({}).toString()
```

or

```
({}.toString()) // This is what repl.js does
```

If you save the example to a file and run it with `node`, by the way, you’ll see that the error still occurs.

Comment: Would it just execute it as an expression always?

Comment: @alex: No, it lets you use `if` and whatnot. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L253